# how to use std::<list>::reverse_iterator with operator +?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I tried this :

```
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
int main()
{
    std::list<int> list(200);
    std::list<int>::reverse_iterator it = list.rbegin() + 100;
}
```

When compiling, it complained that :

```
 error: no operator "-" matches these operands
            operand types are: const std::_List_iterator<int> - std::ptrdiff_t
        balabalabalabalabalabalabalabalabalabalabalabala...
```

I tried the same code on `std::vector`,which works pretty well. My question is how to use `std::<list>::reverse_iterator` with `operator +`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::list` does not have random access iterators. This mean you cannot increment them by arbitrary amounts. What you can do is increment them with either of the `++` operators:

```
std::list<int>::reverse_iterator it = list.rbegin()++;
```

or

```
std::list<int>::reverse_iterator it = ++(list.rbegin());
```

You may also use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) or [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to perform more than one step, but internally, these will step one by one. Traversing a list is an O(N) operation.

For exmple,

```
std::list<int>::reverse_iterator it = std::next(list.rbegin(), 100);
```

or

```
std::list<int>::reverse_iterator it = list.rbegin();
std::advance(it, 100);
```

In both cases, `++` will be applied 100 times. So if you need to do this often, it may be better to use `std::vector` rather than `std::list`, since these operations are O(1) for vectors. In fact, you should have very strong reasons to use choose `list` over `vector`. It is rarely a good choice.

Comment: Or `std::advance` / `std::next`, though it's probably overkill for this case.

Comment: Thx man! Just wondering, why no random access iterator were provided?

Comment: @Alan.W It is a linked list, so you have to step from one node to the next.

Comment: @Alan.W Then definitely `std::advance` or, in C++11, `std::next`.

Comment: @Alan.W I added examples, but it looks to me like you really should be using an `std::vector<int>`. There is hardly ever a good reason to prefer `std::list` over `std::vector`.

Comment: @T.C. Right. Added examples with `next` and `advance`.

Comment: @Alan.W: Do you understand what a linked list is?

Comment: @SiyuanRen Haha I know.. Actually the first time juanchopanza mentioned  it, I've realized what's going on here. But it's really a great experience to read the nice answers from you guys. Learned a lot. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`std::list` has a **bidirectional** iterator. `operator +` is not defined for bidirectional iterators. It is defined only for **random access** iterators as for example iterators of `std::vector`. You have to use standard functions `std::next` and `std::prev` for bidirectional iterators that in turn use `operator ++` or `operator --` for iterators required number of times.

For example you could write

```
std::list<int>::reverse_iterator it = std::next( list.rbegin(), 100 );
```

provided that the list has such a number of elements.

Functions `std::next` and `std::prev` are declared in header `<iterator>`

An alternative function  is standard function `std::advance`.